# Antiderivative of fraction, wrong coefficient

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

$$\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}-e}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Is what I need the antiderivative of. I separated it into 
$$\frac{x^2}{x^{1/2}}-\frac{x^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}}-\frac{e}{x^{1/2}}$$ 
then to
$$x^{1/2}-1-ex^{-1/2}$$
and then took the antiderivative getting
$$\frac{2}{3}x^{3/2}-x-2ex^{1/2}+c$$

The answer I've got is showing that instead of 2/3 as the first coefficient it should be 2/5. I really don't see how you'd get that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second step: $x^2/x^{1/2}=x^{3/2}$ and not $x^{1/2}$.